# How to solve the following integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

Is there any method to solve the following integral equation, either analytically or numerically:

$$A(t) cos(\omega t) + \int_0^t \omega A(\tau) sin(\omega \tau) d\tau = f(t)$$

Where:
$$A(t): unknown\ function\ which\ must\ be\ found$$
$$\omega: angular\ frequency\,\ an\ arbitrary\ positive\ value$$
$$t: time$$
$$f(t): known\ function$$

Comment: Just a thought: differentiating both sides and isolating a derivative results in a linear equation,$$A'(t)+(\omega-1)\tan(\omega t)A(t)=f'(t)\sec(\omega t)$$

Comment: Any ideas or anything you've tried should go in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate, you get a differential equation:

$$
  A'(t) \cos \omega t - \omega A(t) \sin \omega t
    = \omega A(t) \sin \omega t + f'(t)
$$

Linear, first order, thus solvable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I think you have made a mistake while differentiating. Sine terms cancel each other.